# Will a system restore fix constant crashing/freezing issues?

Tags: freeze, troubleshooting

My recent installation 10.10 on my laptop keeps freezing/crashing on start-up after working perfectly for one day.

The system just freezes, like a screenshot, and a restart is required. It happens directly after login or just as any application is selected.

Nothing new has been installed. I have just moved from XP.

Will a system restore fix this like in windows? like i said, nothing new has been installed.

help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, assuming you are a new linux users and didn't changed any setting on your systems that would turn it unstable, no, a reinstall (there is no system restore option) will not help.

You will need to troubleshoot the issue.

Switch to a text console with: CTRL + ALT + F1
login, check the contents of the files under /var/log, there maybe an error related to the hang.

Comment: Cheers, I see many files under var/log, which one will list the errors issued by the crashing?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19538/how-do-you-diagnose-constant-crashing-issues